# How to toggle drawer navigator in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using drawer navigation. When I click on the hamburger menu icon the drawer of the drawer navigation is not working, I am not able to toggle the drawer. Code 1 is not working but code 2 is working, can anyone help me figure out why ?

Code:

```
    Burger menu icon code 1:

    // Inside Header
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                // headerTitle: 'Rchampz',
                headerLeft:
                <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => {navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())} }>
                    <MenuImage navigation={navigation}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>,

//Created component and added inside navigationOptions

    const MenuImage = ({navigation}) => {
        if(!navigation.state.isDrawerOpen){
            return <TouchableOpacity><Image source={require('../assets/images/menu.png')} style={{width: 24, height: 24, resizeMode: 'contain' ,marginLeft: 15}}/></TouchableOpacity>
        }else{
            return <MenuIcon style={{paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10}} name="md-arrow-back" size={30} color="black"/>
        }
    }

    Burger menu icon code 2:

    //Inside header

    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                // headerTitle: 'Rchampz',
                headerLeft:
                <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => {navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())} }>
                    <MenuImage navigation={navigation}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>,


//Created component and added inside navigationOptions

    const MenuImage = ({navigation}) => {
        if(!navigation.state.isDrawerOpen){
            return <MenuIcon style={{paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10}} name="md-menu" size={30} color="black"/>
        }else{
            return <MenuIcon style={{paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10}} name="md-arrow-back" size={30} color="black"/>
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way that you have setup your menu image in the first one. You wrapped the Image within another `TouchableOpacity` which means that the inner `TouchableOpacity` is picking up the user touch event. This is not actually the behavior you want because you want the `TouchableOpacity` on headerLeft to be the receiver of the input. So simply remove the "extra" `TouchableOpacity`.

```
// Inside Header
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft:
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())} }>
        <MenuImage navigation={navigation}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>,

//Created component and added inside navigationOptions
const MenuImage = ({navigation}) => {
    if(!navigation.state.isDrawerOpen){
        // No need of Touchable here. Since you want the above Touchable to pick up the onPress event.
        return <Image source={require('../assets/images/menu.png')} style={{width: 24, height: 24, resizeMode: 'contain' ,marginLeft: 15}}/>. 
    }else{
        return <MenuIcon style={{paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10}} name="md-arrow-back" size={30} color="black"/>
    }
}
```

The reason why the second example works is simply that, there is no extra `Touchable` handling the onPress event.

Comment: Oh ok understood so I was using touchable opacity twice once in NavigationOptions and 2nd time inside MenuImage component so I just need to use 1 touchableopacity i.e inside navigationOptions only am I right ?

Comment: That's correct. Because when you have one inside the other, the most inner one will accept the onPress event first. (Unless you had disabled the inner one or something like that.)